# How do I use the Mono.CSharp interpreter in Microsoft.NET

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, mono

I was under the impression Mono's compiler was [usable in Microsoft.NET](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-27.html)

edit: [updated blog posting here](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-24.html) that I originally missed that explains some of it (is consistent with Justin's answers)

I created a simple class to try to use it

```
[TestFixture]
class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void EXPR()
    {
        Evaluator.Run("using System;");

        int sum = (int)Evaluator.Evaluate("1+2");

    }
}
```

And a project in Visual Studio 2010 that references C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.1\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.CSharp.dll.

However when I try to run this task I get the following exception, thrown at the Evaluator.Run call:

```
    System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
      Message=The type initializer for 'Mono.CSharp.Evaluator' threw an exception.
      Source=Mono.CSharp
      TypeName=Mono.CSharp.Evaluator
      StackTrace:
           at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Run(String statement)
           at Experiments.Class1.EXPR() in W:\Experiments\Class1.cs:line 16
      InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
           Message=Method 'Mono.CSharp.Location.ToString()' is security transparent, but is a member of a security critical type.
           Source=Mono.CSharp
           TypeName=Mono.CSharp.Location.ToString()
           StackTrace:
                at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator..cctor()
           InnerException:
```

A google confirms one other person asking this question but no answer. I tried to start reading [the microsoft article on security transparent code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191569.aspx) but got confused quite quickly. Would someone be able to suggest a quick workaround to allow me to use this? And possibly summarise the security implications, if any, to me (in the context of my situation - in the future I hope to package it with a thick client application, to be used both internally and by end-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a [bug in Mono](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=689473).

.NET 4 abandoned [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but kept the concept of [Security Transparent Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191569.aspx). In a nutshell, low-level code that does stuff, like call unmanaged code, must be "security critical". Application level code is marked "transparent". "Transparent" code cannot call into "security critical" code.

It sounds like Mono.CSharp.Location.ToString() needs to be marked with the [SecuritySafeCritical] attribute if you want the Mono 2.10 code to work with .NET 4. Maybe even better would be marking all of Mono.CSharp as [SecuritySafeCritical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitysafecriticalattribute.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx

PS. Sorry to have multiple answers for one question. After I realized that 2.11 would work, I became more curious about what the error with 2.10 meant. I cannot really combine this answer with the others.

Answer (score 6):

It has worked under .NET since April of [last year](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-27.html).

Small point but I notice you are missing a semi-colon in your expression for `sum`.

`int sum = (int)Evaluator.Evaluate("1+2;");`

I only have Mono 2.11 (from git) at the moment and they have changed to using a multi-instance version of the compiler instead of the static version. So, my code looks a little different:

```
using System;
using Mono.CSharp;

namespace REPLtest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var r = new Report (new ConsoleReportPrinter ());
            var cmd = new CommandLineParser (r);

            var settings = cmd.ParseArguments (args);
            if (settings == null || r.Errors > 0)
                Environment.Exit (1);

            var evaluator = new Evaluator (settings, r);

            evaluator.Run("using System;");

            int sum = (int) evaluator.Evaluate("1+2;");

            Console.WriteLine ("The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}", sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I guess I should confirm that I did in fact successfully execute this on .NET 4 (using Visual C# Express 2010 on Windows XP)

**EDIT AGAIN:** If you have Visual Studio, you can [download the latest version of Mono.CSharp](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.CSharp) and compile it yourself. There is a .sln (solution file) included with the source so you can build it on Windows without Mono. The resulting assembly would run the code above. Miguel has a post explaining the new Mono.CSharp [here](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-24.html).

**FINAL EDIT:** I uploaded the compiled Mono.CSharp.dll assembly that I actually used [here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/MO5U1YmA/Mono.CSharp.dll.html). Include it as a reference to compile the code above.

Comment: David Ebbo's also posted the latest version to NuGet:
https://nuget.org/packages/Mono.CSharp

Answer (score 3):

I decided I should have kept the code more like the question but I did not want to overwrite my previous answer:

The code below works with version 2.11 of Mono.CSharp (available [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.CSharp) including a solution file for building with Visual Studio/.NET). It was tested with .NET 4 on Windows XP. I do not have access to Mono 2.10 at the moment.

```
[TestFixture]
class Class1
{
    private Evaluator evaluator;

    public Class1()
    {
        var report = new Report(new ConsoleReportPrinter());
        evaluator = new Evaluator(new CompilerSettings(), report);
    }

    [Test]
    public void EXPR()
    {
        evaluator.Run("using System;");

        int sum = (int)evaluator.Evaluate("1+2;");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I uploaded the Mono.CSharp.dll assembly that I actually used [here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/MO5U1YmA/Mono.CSharp.dll.html). Include it as a reference to compile the code above.